# Cordova iOs shows Keyboard for no Reason in SAPUI5 Application on View Trasition

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, sapui5

The keyboard opens when the new view is shown. The native objective-c code shows, that the `keyboardWillShow` notification is thrown.

The Safari debugger shows me that the HTML body tag is active when the keyboard opens. Which seems to make no sense.

Is this a Safari bug? How can I solve this? I need to prevent that the keyboard opens. Or better to find out what causes the keyboard to open.

My first approach was to call `document.getElementById(document.activeElement.id).blur()` this works as long as the debugger is running. Probably a issue in the timing (the keyboard has first tobe open before it can be closed again.)

Answer (score 0):

You mean view transitions within a NavContainer/App control? This control focuses the first focusable element in the new page/view - and if it is an input field, this may open the keyboard on touch devices. Is this your situation?

This behavior is a known issue and a solution being worked on now. As a workaround, you can try adding a focusable element BEFORE the input field.

Comment: does not work, because the  `document.activeElement` is the body of the HTML site. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, you say the keyboard opens without the focus being in an input field? That's strange. Actually calling blur() on the focused input field is supposed to even close the keyboard. Keyboard open with focus on the body doesn't make a lot of sense... no idea...  (btw: in 1.30 the NavContainer/App control may likely have an "autoFocus" property where the focus behavior can be turned off. This is being added as we speak.)